# Uninstall EntityFramework using the Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to re-install my EntityFramework package using

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

But I get the following message

> 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already installed.  already has a reference to
>   'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.

So I tried to uninstall the package using

```
PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

But I keep on getting the following message

```
Uninstall-Package : Unable to find package 'EntityFramework'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
```

How do I re-install the package?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try deleting it out of the project references, and out of `packages.config`.  Then re-add it.

Comment: Thank you, removed the references and deleted packages.config. Installed successfully. +1

Answer (score 16):

To remove/uninstall:
In the Package Manager Console run:

> UnInstall-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Try it without -Force.
2. Try to specify -ProjectName parameter and execute it over each project that includes the EntityFramework package.

Answer (score 1):

You can run following command  in package manager

> UnInstall-Package EntityFramework

Then Install the needed package using

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue, and it came down to an incorrect path. You are unable to find the package as the full namespace for Entity Framework is Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.

Therefore, to uninstall you need to enter the following into the Package Manager:

`Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`

Answer (score 0):

In Package Manager Console you can write following command:

Uninstall-package EntityFramework  -force

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any EntityFramework files are deleted from the File Explorer project folder after you do the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this issue for days. To solve the issue I tried the latest version of framework, uninstalled it and installed previous version. All the possibilities tried were not working for me. At last, I found a solution and just run the below command at Package manger Console.

```
PM>install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
```

everything is done by itself. Uninstalling old version and installing the latest version of Ef under `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.2` and it updates the files of my project by itself.

After installation, the image below show what I have by going to tools->Nuget Packagemanager->package visualizer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deleting packages folder and then rebuilding the solution solved the issue in my case.

Answer (score -2):

if you have the connection string with provider name on it . Then make sure the provider name have definition below as in the config (providers)(provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /)(/providers)

Comment: This is answer doesn't address the question. The question is about handling Nuget via the Package Manager Console, not about connection strings in a web/app.config file.