# What is the best way to remove MS Entity Framework facilities from Prism 6 WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I had added Entity Framework (using Code First - pure code approach) in Prism module which is in my WPF Prism 6 modular application. The name of this module is 'Authorization'. You can see it below at the picture:

[image]

Where 'AuthorizationLevel' and 'UserCredential' classes (in 'EfClasses' folder) are entity classes and 'UserCredentialsContext' class in 'EfClasses' folder is class derived from DbContext type. Also you can see from the picture that Entity Framework facilities were added to Properties ('DataSources' folder), Resources and Settings. But some time later I revealed that Entity Framework is not needed in my application. So I should remove Entity Framework facilities from my application. What is the best way to remove it from my application without crippling and corrupting of my application?

Comment: How did you add Entity Framework (which version) to your project... nuget? Visual Studio template?... if nuget look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653633/uninstall-entityframework-using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: I added it via NuGet.

Comment: Then as per the link I gave... try something like this at the package manager console... UnInstall-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.2 ... as ever backup your project first... then do it... and get the version number correct.

Comment: You mean the version of EF NuGet package I installed?

Comment: Thanks for nice information. I did.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put the solution here so hopefully this will not fall into the 'unanswered' category.

With Nuget packages more often than not you can uninstall them using nuget, in my experience this is a pretty fast and painless solution.

1. Open [Package Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console)
2. Discover the correct name of the package you wish to uninstall
3. [Type the string into the package manager console then press enter](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console#removing-a-package), e.g.

> UnInstall-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.2